# forwarded ref with button OR anchor types - typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to create a button component in react with typescript.
This component should be rendered as an `a`-tag or a `button`-tag in html. So I added the property `as: "a" | "button"` to the component to let the programmer decide which one should be used.

So you should be able to do:

```
<Button as="button" type="submit">I am a button</Button>
<Button as="a">I am a link</Button>
```

It is necessary that the button forwards the ref! Keep that in mind for the next steps.

So the button component should look something like that:

```
import { forwardRef } from "react";

type ButtonPropsBasics = {
  outlined?: boolean;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  className?: string;
};
type ButtonPropsAsButton = React.HTMLAttributes<"button"> & {
  as: "button";
} & ButtonPropsBasics;

type ButtonPropsAsAnchor = React.HTMLAttributes<"a"> & {
  as: "a";
} & ButtonPropsBasics;

type ButtonProps = ButtonPropsAsButton | ButtonPropsAsAnchor;

const Button = forwardRef<HTMLAnchorElement | HTMLButtonElement, ButtonProps>(
  function ForwardedButton(props, ref) {
    const {
      outlined,
      children,
      className,
      as: Component = "a",
      ...rest
    } = props;

    return (
      <Component
        ref={ref}
        className={outlined ? "border-2 border-black" : ""}
        {...rest}
      >
        {/* some other components here */}
        {children}
      </Component>
    );
  }
);

export default Button;
```

The problem here is that the `ref` types do not match the given html element.

So I don't know how to say "if the `as` is an anchor, then use `HTMLAnchorElement` as type of the `forwardedRef` otherwise use the `HTMLButtonElement`.
Any ideas?

See full example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-flower-gh9qtv?file=/src/Button.tsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found a solution for the problem. So we have to say that we want an `IntrinsicElements` of type `a` if  prop `as="a"`.
This allows us to add all props to the given HTML tag and declines al other props which are not supported by this anchor. Same for the `button` tag.

Here the full Code of the Button.tsx:

```
import { forwardRef } from "react";

type ButtonPropsBasics = {
  outlined?: boolean;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  className?: string;
};

type ButtonProps = ButtonPropsBasics &
  (
    | (JSX.IntrinsicElements["a"] & { as?: "a" })
    | (JSX.IntrinsicElements["button"] & { as: "button" })
  );

const Button = forwardRef<HTMLAnchorElement | HTMLButtonElement, ButtonProps>(
  function ForwardedButton(props, ref) {
    const {
      outlined,
      children,
      className,
      as: Component = "a",
      ...rest
    } = props;

    return (
      <Component
        ref={ref as any}
        className={outlined ? "border-2 border-black" : ""}
        {...(rest as any)}
      >
        {/* some other components here */}
        {children}
      </Component>
    );
  }
);

export default Button;
```

This allows us to use the following"

```
<Button as="button" type="submit" outlined={true}>I am an button</Button>
<Button as="a" href="/">I am a link</Button>
```

But does NOT allow:

```
{/* 'href' is not allowed as prop of button */}
<Button as="button" href="/">I am a button</Button>
```

See the full example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-grass-bnvsmn?file=/src/Button.tsx

Answer (score 3):

You can use this (merge ref with rest props):

```
import { forwardRef } from 'react';

type ButtonProps = {
  outlined?: boolean;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  className?: string;
  as: 'button' | 'a';
  type?: 'button' | 'submit' | 'reset';
};

const Button = forwardRef<HTMLAnchorElement | HTMLButtonElement, ButtonProps>(
  function ForwardedButton(props, ref) {
    const { outlined, children, className, as: Component = 'a', ...rest } = props;
    const btnProps = { ...ref, ...rest };

    return (
      <Component className={outlined ? 'border-2 border-black' : ''} {...btnProps}>
        {/* some other components here */}
        {children}
      </Component>
    );
  },
);

export default Button;
```

or this (don't forget /* eslint-disable react/display-name */):

```
/* eslint-disable react/display-name */
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react';

type ButtonProps = {
  outlined?: boolean;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  className?: string;
  as: 'button' | 'a';
  type?: 'button' | 'submit' | 'reset';
};

export type ButtonRef<C extends React.ElementType> = React.ComponentPropsWithRef<C>['ref'];

const Button = forwardRef(
  <C extends React.ElementType>(props: ButtonProps, ref: ButtonRef<C>) => {
    const { outlined, children, as: Component = 'a', ...rest } = props;

    return (
      <Component ref={ref} className={outlined ? 'border-2 border-black' : ''} {...rest}>
        {/* some other components here */}
        {children}
      </Component>
    );
  },
);

export default Button;
```

or this (more generic polymorphic)

```
/* eslint-disable react/display-name */
import React from 'react';

type AsProp<C extends React.ElementType> = {
  as?: C;
};

type PropsToOmit<C extends React.ElementType, P> = keyof (AsProp<C> & P);

type ComponentProp<
  C extends React.ElementType,
  Props = Record<string, unknown>,
> = React.PropsWithChildren<Props & AsProp<C>> &
  Omit<React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<C>, PropsToOmit<C, Props>>;

type ButtonRef<C extends React.ElementType> = React.ComponentPropsWithRef<C>['ref'];

type ComponentPropWithRef<
  C extends React.ElementType,
  Props = Record<string, unknown>,
> = ComponentProp<C, Props> & { ref?: ButtonRef<C> };

type ButtonProps<C extends React.ElementType> = ComponentPropWithRef<
  C,
  { outlined?: boolean; children?: React.ReactNode; className?: string }
>;

const Button = React.forwardRef(
  <C extends React.ElementType = 'span'>(props: ButtonProps<C>, ref?: ButtonRef<C>) => {
    const { outlined, children, as: Component = 'a', ...rest } = props;

    return (
      <Component ref={ref} className={outlined ? 'border-2 border-black' : ''} {...rest}>
        {/* some other components here */}
        {children}
      </Component>
    );
  },
);

export default Button;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answere. The second suggestion is more the solution I need. But your suggestion does not allow me to just hand over all the allowed props for an html `a` or `button` element. So if I call the component and want to add the prop `onClick` this is not possible.
So I have to add all default props of the html elements inside the `ButtonProps` manually. 
Is there a way to add these genetically?

Comment: I've just added the more generic polymorphic button component

Comment: Thank you. Looks like your last approach allows me to add any prop in the end, since it declares every prop as `any`.